# Chatter Auto Follow

Tags: apex, chatter

I am trying to create an Apex class that would take a defined user field from an object, and set as auto follow for that record in chatter. If that field is updated with a new user, then replace the auto follow with that new user. I have written the code bellow with some help, but still having issues when I compile. "Variable does not exist: str.SubsciberId. I am new to Apex, could someone help me?

```
public static void DevOwnerChatSub(Map<Id,Story__c> oldStoryMap, Map<Id,Story__c> newStoryMap)
{

    List<EntitySubscription> newSubscription = new List <EntitySubscription>();
    List<EntitySubscription> updateSubscription = new List <EntitySubscription>();



    for(Id strId:newStoryMap.keySet())
    {
        EntitySubscription stEntity = new EntitySubscription();
        stEntity.ParentId = strId.Id;
        stEntity.SubscriberId = strId.Owner__c;


        Story__c newStory = (Story__c) newStoryMap.get(strId);

        if(newStory.Owner__c != null)
        {
            Story__c oldStory = (Story__c)oldStoryMap.get(strId);                    
            if((oldStory.Owner__c != newStory.Owner__c) && (oldStory.Owner__c !=null))
            {

                str.SubscriberId = newStory.Owner__c;
                updateSubscription.add(newStory);
            }
            else if (oldStory.Owner__c !=null)
            {

                newSubscription.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentID = newStory.Id, SubscriberId = newStory.Owner__c));
            }
        }
    }

    try{
        Database.insert(newSubscription);
        Database.update(updateSubscription);
    }
    catch (DMLException dmlEx){
        if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0)==statusCode.Duplicate_Value) {
            System.Debug('DevOwnerChatSub: subscription already exists');
        } else{
            throw dmlEx;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which object is "str" - str.SubscriberId = newStory.Owner__c;
? I don't see it in this class.

Comment: SubscriberId is a field on the EntitySubscription object. I think I have to create an EntitySubscription Map?

Comment: Your logic is little confusing. Also, "updateSubscription.add(newStory);" line will error out. You try to add Story__c to List<EntitySubscription>.

Comment: Database.insert and Database.update will never throw exceptions. Check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

Comment: @SLman That is completely incorrect. They will throw exceptions unless you specify `allOrNone` as `false` (it defaults to `true`).

Comment: str is not assigned any value, so it is expected to error out.